Can transactions with multiple instructions be sandwiched or rearranged between your individual instructions?
For example, say you have a transaction where you combined program deployment and setting the admin/owner controls in a initialize instruction. Is there a way for an attacker to rearrange the transactions in a block to allow your program to deploy but call your own initialization instruction before yours?
Of course, I can just hardcode the initial admin but say I wanted to re-initialize some PDA. Can an attacker intercept a transaction which closes an account and re-initializes it?

Transactions are atomic on Solana, so it's impossible for an attacker to reorganize individual instructions within a transaction.
More info at https://solana.com/docs/terminology#transaction
